# Adding HTTP Headers on SoapServer Response

Tags: php, http, soap, soapheader, soapserver

Is there a way to add an HTTP Header in a response of a SoapServer.

For example: I want the response of my SoapServer to add
"Location", "http://localhost"

> HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
>
> Location: http://localhost
>
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
>
> Content-Length: 100

Comment: Are you using `SoapClient` provided by PHP?

Comment: @abdulrashid Yes

Comment: Read this http://mycodde.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-use-php-soapclient-tls-request.html

Comment: did you find answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SoapServer, just add:

```
header('Location: http://localhost');
```

this will automatically add the 'Location' header as well as change the response code.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way to add more data to Soap is

```
function add_custom_data() {

            $outerObj = new stdClass();
            $innerObj = new stdClass();
            $innerObj->data1 = "MyData";
            $innerObj->data2 = "MyData2";
            $outerObj->innerObj = $innerObj;

            return $outerObj;
}
```

For Soap the Definition File has to match the elements in the Request / Response.